# Apply color defined in string

Tags: html, css, vue.js

Currently we update an old product with VueJs. In the old application we use Spring Web Flow. Now the whole information how the text is eidted is stored in a string. I already found out, that using

```
white-space: pre-line;
```

as style in the div can resolve symboles like \n and show the string correctly.

Now my question is, is there a style to resolve something like

```
{color:red|ATTENTION:}
```

to apply the color to the text?

To make it a bit clearer. I got a string from the backend which should be inserted  in a . The string could look like this:

`"This is a header\r\n\r\nThis is a Body.\r\n\r\n{color:red|This should be red:}\r\n\r\n"`

I tried to find out where this kind of syntax is used, without success.

Comment: You will have to process the sting and output html

Answer (score 0):

You can bind style as simple as that
`<div style="{color: 'red'}"></div>`

Comment: Hi, I know, but the prblem is I get the whole text with all configurations as a string. I have no possibility to split the text and do it manually. Furthermore, the string depends on the current situation